# How to include submodules when the relitive path changes

Tags: git, gitlab

I have a project that includes submodules using relative paths. When I clone the project to my personal workspace there is one less sub folder and hence all my relative paths to the submodules fail.

I don't want to change the path to use absolute paths that include the submodules as this is an issue when I check out the folders using ssh, but the build server uses https.

So, on the main project the submodule would be

```
../../projectA
```

In my clone:

```
../projectA
```

Is there anyway to create a submodule link that would use my current repository base url?

I would clone the project using:

```
git clone git:server.corp.net:sub/test/mainproject.git
git clone git:server.corp.net:cloned/mainproject.git
```

Submodules are located:

```
server.corp.net/projectA.git
```